# Configuring WebSphere Commerce Developer 6.0 to use WebSphere Application Server 6.1

Tags: websphere, websphere-7, websphere-6.1, ibm-rad, websphere-commerce

Has anyone successfully configured WebSphere Commerce Developer 6.0 to use WAS 6.1 and RAD 7.0?

I'm working on a site implemented with IBM WebSphere Commerce Developer 6.0. In production the site runs on WebSphere Application Server 6.1, which is officially supported. We'd like to run our local developer environments on WAS 6.1 as well, but the migration instructions cover only stand-alone servers. Commerce Developer is limited to WAS 6.0 according to the documentation below:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.commerce.admin.doc%2Ftasks%2Ftmgwas61.htm

We're hoping to be able to leverage Java 5 support and other features of WAS 6.1 while staying on WebSphere Commerce Developer 6.0. We have some portions of the code developed using Java 5, but currently we have to deploy this code to a stand-alone server to test, which is less than ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.. can't be done.   The issue is that the runtime and tooling is all linked together.